# Read system call for a file residing on a smb mount hangs forever if network connection is broken?

Tags: linux, network-programming, blocking, smb

I have mounted a windows shared folder on a centos box. When i try to read a huge file using read system call and if network connection breaks then the read simply hangs and puts my program into a uninterruptible sleep state. This does not sound right. Even if i open the file using O_NONBLOCK even then the read does hang. I was hoping that read will eventually time out but it does not. 
How do you implement a reliable copy operation over network if the read is simply going to block without returning any error? 
I dont think the using async mode And select call is going to help me either.
Is read always a blocking call?
Thanks
Ghanaku

Comment: You may get a better response if post some snippets of code and your Smb configuration, obviously removing any sensitive information first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try mounting the remote filesystem as cifs instead of smb. [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) supports the `soft` options (and it is the default too) that will cause an error to be returned in the case of a network or server failure instead of a hang.

From the man page:

> soft: (default) The program accessing a file on the cifs mounted file system will not hang when the server crashes and will return errors to the user application.